# type null is not a subtype of type 'String' error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

```
 body: StreamBuilder<List<User>>(
        stream: readUsers(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error ${snapshot.error}');
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final users = snapshot.data!;

            return ListView(
              children: users.map(buildUser).toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      )),
```

The part where I am trying to pull data from firebase.

```
  Widget buildUser(User user) => ListTile(leading: Text('${user.bmi}'));
```

The buildUser widget I created.

```
  Stream<List<User>> readUsers() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .snapshots()
  .map((snapshot) =>
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => User.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
```

The readUser structure I created

I am able to print data to the database and one of these data is a double value named 'bmi'. When I continue the process, it stays in the snapshot.haserror loop and

**type null is not a subtype of type 'String'**

prints the error.

```
    class User {
  final double bmi;

  User(
      {
      required this.bmi});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'bmi': bmi,
      };

  static User fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
      bmi: json['bmi']);
}
```

Comment: Could you specify where exactly error happen?

Comment: I am getting some values ​​on the previous page from the user. Then I go to the page with the error with a button. It also prints the error I asked in the question inside the page.

Comment: maybe your error come from another model , in this class your provided there is no string type at all

Answer (score 2):

i am not 100% sure, but i had the same error, where the json did not have that specific field. Before you try to get the 'bmi' field of json, check if it exists:

```
json.containsKey("bmi") ? json['bmi'] : "missing field"
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed.